Can mitmproxy be used to block WebSockets from a SignalR Client when used as a proxy for them?
In order to test some networking conditions for a project, I need to block the use of websockets for a SignalR. The easiest way to do this seemed to be a proxy and mitmproxy seemed suitable.
After messing around with mitmproxy for most of the evening, I was unable to get WebSockets blocked with any basic filtering or use of the block_list.
My block_list contained just: :~websocket:444 but this didn't appear to do anything.
I also tried blocking them using a Python based Addon for mitmproxy. The code of which is below:
import logging
from mitmproxy import http
from mitmproxy import ctx

class BlockWebSockets:

    def block_websocket(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        logging.info("Blocking WebSocket request to %s" % flow.request.pretty_url)
        flow.response = http.Response.make(
            403,
            b"WebSocket connections are not allowed",
            {"Content-Type": "text/html"}
        )
    def request(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        if flow.request.headers.get("Upgrade", "").lower() == "websocket" or flow.websocket:
            self.block_websocket(flow)
    def websocket_start(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        self.block_websocket(flow)
    def websocket_handshake(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        self.block_websocket(flow)

    def http_connect(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        if flow.request.headers.get("Upgrade", "").lower() == "websocket" or flow.websocket:
            self.block_websocket(flow)
        else:
            logging.info(bytes(flow.request.headers))

    def websocket_message(self, flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
        # If somehow WebSocket messages get through, this will kill them
        logging.info("Blocking WebSocket message to %s" % flow.request.pretty_url)
        flow.intercept()
        flow.kill()

addons = [
    BlockWebSockets()
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from mitmproxy.tools.main import mitmdump
    mitmdump(["-s", __file__])

Strangely this setup does work with a basic Websocket setup:
var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
ws.Options.Proxy = new WebProxy("localhost:8080");

... Regular connection logic...

However, this doesn't work for SignalR.
My SignalR Setup is also very simple, with just a few extra items to make the Proxy be picked up:
// Proxy is a WebProxy instance defined elsewhere in this class but basically:
var Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8080");

var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(SignalREndpoint, options =>
    {
        // If we have a proxy, pass it to Signal R too
        if (Proxy != null)
        {
            options.Proxy = Proxy;

            //These seemed excessive but like I said most of the evening was spent trying to figure it out.
            options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (handler) =>
            {
                if (handler is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                {
                    clientHandler.Proxy = Proxy;
                }

                return handler;
            };

            // Based on: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.FunctionalTests/HubConnectionTests.cs,2754
            options.WebSocketFactory = async (context, token) =>
            {
                var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
                ws.Options.Proxy = Proxy;
                await ws.ConnectAsync(context.Uri, token);
                return ws;
            };
            options.WebSocketConfiguration = wsOptions =>
            {
                wsOptions.Proxy = Proxy;
            };
        }
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect(new InfiniteRetryPolicy(0, 2, 5, 10, 15, 30))
    .Build();

In mitmproxy, I don't see any of my messages added in the addon. I do see a lot of "CONNECT"'s in the mitmproxy logs though.
I thought the connects might indicate having the same issues as you might with proxying WebSockets over NGINX, Specifically:

One is that WebSocket is a hop‑by‑hop protocol, so when a proxy server
intercepts an Upgrade request from a client it needs to send its own
Upgrade request to the backend server, including the appropriate
headers.

Does anyone have any ideas?
